# Cant use dictionary outside function

Tags: c#, .net

Situation is as following: I am trying to use an dictionary in C# (.NET Framework in Visual Studio) point is that whenever I put the Dictionary outside of an function it does not seem to work.

This is how I would want it to be:

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

Dictionary<string, string> countriesMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
countriesMap.Add("Parijs", "7,13");

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    locater();
}
```

This is how I am now doing this, but this is inconvenient since I need to use the dictionary in multiple functions.

```cs
private string randomGetter()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> countriesMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    countriesMap.Add("Parijs", "7,13");
}
```

Is there something wrong with my VS setup or is this just not possible and should I work around it?

Comment: You're halfway there - keep the declaration and initialization (`Dictionary<string, string> countriesMap = ...`) outside of the method, then call `countriesMap.Add()` _inside_ the load method.

Comment: You can't write arbitrary code out of functions. The Dictionary field isn't the problem, putting `countriesMap.Add("Parijs", "7,13");` at the class level is. Fill the dictionary in the constructor or make sure it's fully initialized when declared, eg `Dictionary<string, string> countriesMap = new Dictionary<string, string>{ ["Parijs"]= "7,13"};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add method call has to be inside a method or constructor. You could add it as part of your dictionary initializer.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    countriesMap.Add("Parijs", "7,13");
}

Dictionary<string, string> countriesMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

As part of the initializer would look like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> countriesMap = new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"Parijs", "7,13"}};
```